# Сложная выборка данных SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Нужно выбрать все данные для таблицы постройки. Особенно интересует в какой области она находится.

[image: Примерная схема данных]

Comment: А чего сложного-то? `SELECT * from Постройки as a JOIN Улицы as b ON a.Улицы_id = b.id JOIN ...` и таким же образом `JOIN` подставляете дальше сами и всё :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  p.*,
  u.`name`,
  n.`name`,
  r.`name`,
  o.`name`
from 
  `Постройки` p
  join `Улицы` u on p.`Улицы_id` = u.`ID`
  join `Населенные пункты` n on u.`Населенные пункты_id` = n.`ID`
  join `Районы` r on n.`Районы_id` = r.`ID`
  join `Области` o on r.`Область_id` = o.`ID`
```